# How to intercept all touch events and detect it's consumers

Tags: android

How to intercept all touch events within activity, and detect the event's consumer? For simplifying let's assume I have to log all events like this: `ImageView -> onLongClick()`.

The actual problem is actually to detect event's consumer - to intercept all events I can add overlay on the top of activity view, or override `dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` in the activity, but I have no idea how to detect consumer of such event.

Answer (score 0):

If you override dispatchTouchEvent in the Activity ,that means all the event will be intercepted by Activity.

Any view in this Activity will not get any message because you've already consumer it .

I don't know why you want to do this , but If you wanna learn or something ,you can read something about android view event .

Comment: Not correct, if I will override `dispatchTouchEvent` and inside of it I will call super implementation, children will get events as before, and I'll be able to log events.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135225/no-implementation-of-gesturedetector-will-work-on-android-app/46136919#46136919). The `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` method of an **activity** will be called when there aren't any child views in this activity handle this event. So you should override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` of **your overlay view**
 (**IMPORTANT: return true;** in this method).

Comment: OK, but how to detect which view will consume touch event?

Comment: if your overlay view is on the top. You only override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` method of this view(remember `return true;` that's mean that the overlay view is handled the `MotionEvent` and `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` method of the others are not called).

Comment: The key here is not to disrupt original event propagation so I definitely want `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` of children to be called.